# D3 stacked bars data structure

Tags: d3.js

I have data that I want to visualize as a stacked bar chart (or whatever might be suitable):

```
{
    "ep1": {
        "avi": 29,
        "mov": 17,
        "mp3": 19
    },
    "ep2": {
        "avi": 13,
        "mp3": 49,
        "mp4": 37,
        "xyz": 5
    },
    ...
}
```

However, looking at various D3 as well as NVD3 examples (e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967), I'm not sure how to transform my data - whose groups are not the same across different columns - into the required data structure.

I'd be grateful for a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a method to normalize a bit your data (eventually setting the `xyz` attribute of your `ep1` object to zero for example), you can use the stack layout offered by D3. You will need to change the data structure from an array of objects to an array of arrays (as explained [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#wiki-_stack)) with all 2nd dimensional arrays having the same length, hence the need to set `xyz` to zero in the example.